# How can I query postgres by page?

Tags: postgresql

Assume a table that has many pages and I only want some of it, for example

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE...
```

From pg_class.relpages I know how many pages are there, how can I access some page like

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE PAGE_NUMBER=1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "page"? How is the size of such a "page" determined?

Comment: If you have physical storage pages in mind - do not do it. One of the reasons relational databases exist is to manage data by logical means only and Postgresql is particularly good at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention relpages I assume you are talking about "physical" pages where the data is stored on disk.  In general you should mind your own business and let the database server mind its own business.  But if you don't want to do that, the you can reference tuples by the hidden system column  "ctid", which is a composite consisting of the page number and the slot within the page.

```
select * from pgbench_accounts where ctid between '(18,0)' and '(18,65535)';
```

This is the 19th page, as page numbers start at 0.  Slot numbers start at 1, but for convenience you are allowed to reference slot 0 as if it were a valid (but empty) slot.

Note that until very recent versions, this will not be fast as it would scan the whole table and filter out the disqualified rows one by one.

Comment: This is nice, but wonder this basic operation has such a disastrous execution plan, anyhow for older version i think following query should help


SELECT * FROM t WHERE ctid = ANY (ARRAY(SELECT format('(%s,%s)', i, j)::tid
    FROM generate_series(1000,1999) AS gs(i), generate_series(1,200)
AS gs2(j)));

From https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2400034

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need a sort order. For example

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ...
ORDER BY customer, created_ts;
```

Make sure that the sort condition is unique. If it isn't, add the primary key at the end.
Then you create an index for the `ORDER BY` condition:

```
CREATE INDEX ON t (customer, created_ts);
```

Then you select the first page of 50 items like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ...
ORDER BY customer, created_ts
LIMIT 50;
```

You display the page and remember `customer` and `created_ts` from the *last result row* in `<latest_cust>` and `<latest_ts>`.

The next page is fetched with

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ...
AND (customer, created_ts) > (<latest_cust>, <latest_ts>)
ORDER BY customer, created_ts
LIMIT 50;
```

and so on.

This method (it is called “keyset pagination”) is efficient and quite stable in the face of concurrent data modifications.